# Is "That's him I talked to" natural?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> *That's him. **That's him I talked to.***

The emboldened part is not natural, right? What would be natural instead?

Comment: It's movie script dialogue. It would fit certain characters.

Comment: It depends on the context. If this is a dialogue in a movie where a character is pointing out someone, it’s completely natural.

Comment: Sounds dialectal, but natural in, say, Yorkshire. I don't know how you'd find evidence for it, though. The grammar is the same as “That's him who I talked to.”, but with “who” elided.

Answer (score 1):

Completely natural spoken and **non-standard** English.  It would be typical of many urban dialects in the UK.

For learners, you should probably avoid this structure, certainly in writing, probably in speech, unless you are very confident in your ability. It is very hard for a non-native speaker to speak "badly" on purpose, and for it to seem natural and effective.  People will assume that you've just made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not natrual.

> That's him. **That's him I talked to.**

Try this

> That's him. That's who I talked to.

or this

> That's him. That's the one I talked to.

or this

> That's him. I talked to him!

Comment: Do you mean not natural for a native speaker, or not correct standard English? It seems quite natural to me, though not standard English

Comment: Well when I read it, I initially thought as you. However after saying it out loud a couple of times and imagining myself actual point to the guy whilst saying it, I had to admit there is no way I would say that, in that instance.  That's him I talked to. That's him - yes.... or That's him. I talked to him! or That's him. That's who I talked to. or That's him. That's the one I talked to. but not

Comment: This fits with it being non-standard English. ***You*** would never say it, and I wouldn't either, but I can certainly picture other native speakers saying it, especially from certain parts of the UK.